# Exception with Devise is password is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want users to interact with my site without having to create an account and then later create an account (supply password, name info..etc) if they want more.

This works fine but if user thought they've created an account and then tried to login (likely using a password they use all the time) Devise will through an Exception:

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash in Devise/sessionsController#create
```

Because password is nil. If they go through the signup and then signin again, it works.

I'm using devise (1.2.0), Rails (3.0.4) and Ruby 1.9.2

I mean I can go around it by creating a dummy password and have a field to say if the user has signed up (or check if other mandatory fields have been provided) then resetting the password on actual sign up but I think in all cases it shouldn't through the above exception.

Is there anything I can do/set to go around the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to just generate a random one, using something like `Devise.friendly_token[0..20]` but you could also override the Devise controller and method for logging in, rescue the exception, and just redirect.